# What is Neodymium?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, elements

What is [Neodymium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium)? I'm not quite sure why i was redirected here. I was curious about magnets. I wondered how magnetizing a drill bit worked. I originally wanted to know how long the magnetization would last. Google gave a 3 part response. The temporary magnetization, the Neodymium, which would lose 1% of it's power over a 10 year period and another one, which i cant remember the nomenclature of, that lasts indefinitely. I am open to the theory that everything in this universe is connected. I figured, maybe a better understanding of this would open up doors to other things. Not too sure why. But the simple fact that I asked a question that required me to verify myself for, piqued my interest.  Gave my weird little thought process some type of exclusivity. Otherwise, nobody in the world would have ever heard how my question came about. Nobody probably cares, either. Welcome to my weird world. Maybe I can see urs

Comment: [Neodymium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium) is an element, like hydrogen, carbon, or uranium.

Comment: So, can that be applied to another piece of metal through magnetization or is magnetization strictly temporary? I assume, being an element , it has to be natural. Pure curiosity, here...

Comment: I think most magnets tend to demagnetize over time as the magnetic moments of their atoms lose their alignment. (Some atoms act like little magnets.) Neodymium is a naturally-occurring element that we mine. It is highly magnetizable, meaning that the magnetic moments of its atoms can be easily induced to align under the influence of a temporary magnetic field, and then they mostly hold their alignment for a long time.

Comment: As far as magnetizing tools goes, many tools can be magnetized by stroking a strong magnet along the length of the tool, in one direction, several times, using the same pole of the magnet. I do this to screwdrivers often. Neodymium can be found in the periodic table.

Comment: @Jeremy Cancelo Any element on the periodic table is a naturally occurring element by itself. I.e iron, carbon, neodymium, gold, cobalt and helium and argon. They are not like compounds or made up of other materials. Magnetization is temporary. Since magnets lose their magnetic field over time. Then they have to be re-magnetized. Being an element it is naturally occurring. I'm foggy on what questions you're asking, but I hope I helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Neodymium is just another element like oxygen and sodium. The neodymium magnet is an alloy consisting of neodymium, iron and boron. The unique properties of this alloy make it very suitable for making large and powerful magnets.

Specifically, the alloy has really high retentivity (which allows for large magnetic fields) and high coercivity (ability to withstand external changes). You might also want to look into [hysterisis loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) if you want to know how the material is magnetised.

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help :) If this has answered your question, you can accept and close the question to let others know.